# mod_rewrite Internal rewrite with the new URL showing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using Mod_Rewrite to rewrite (internal) some old pages to new pages on my site.

This works:

```
RewriteRule ^thispage\.html$ thatpage.html
```

The problem is that the page changes to the new page (this is good!), but does not change the (URL) name from "thispage" to "thatpage" so the user gets hinted to the new address.  Apache (2.x) states to place a `[R]` after the above script, i.e.,

```
RewriteRule ^thispage\.html$ thatpage.html [R]
```

This supposedly lets the user know it is changed and sends them to the new page.

When I add the `[R]`, I get a 500 error.  The server is an Apache/1.3.33.

I am thinking that the only way to force the server to show the new url is to use a redirect instead on rewrite. Any ideas?

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: Just adding ` [R]` should work. Do you have anything else inside your htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
RewriteRule ^thispage.html$ thatpage.html [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, a Redirect would be easier on the server than a Rewrite...

```
Redirect 301 thispage.html http://yourDomain.com/thatpage.html
```

Answer (score 0):

For not display new url, you must delete [R], because
[R] is for display new url